# LinkedIn RichMedia upload

Tags: linkedin-api

I uploaded an image to LinkedIn using [richmedia API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares#upload) and created a post using [Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api#post) and this is the post [link](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6489391786451181568). But the created post has distorted image like below with gray bars on the sides of the image. 
[image: Distorted image with gray bars]

When I am uploading the same image directly via LinkedIn it is getting resized and the image is showed without any gray bars.

Why am I seeing this issue while creating the media with LinkedIn API?

Is there any resolution limitations for media upload via API? If there is what are those limitations?

Original image which I am trying to upload:

[image: Original image which I am trying upload]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hey priyanka even im trying to post to Linkedin from API, but image is going as link, not how you are doing, Can you please share the code how you are doing? and which language you are using. Thank

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz would sharing a postman collection of the list of calls what you need to make to get the image as is but not as link works for you?

Comment: No image going as link is not working for me. Yeah can you please share postman collection to ssalmanriyaz@gmail.com

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz  This https://stackoverflow.com/a/54441630/3351074 contains the list of curl commands which helps you to create an image share in LinkedIn company page.

Comment: @priyanka. How do you upload your image? Can you please provide some base code. please )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the reason why LinkedIn is adding padding to the image when an image is uploaded via Rich Media API.

[Reference for the below description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#optimize-rich-media-shares-for-mobile)

LinkedIn recommends that you upload rich media in 1200 x 627 aspect ratio. Images uploaded in the recommended 1200 x 627 ratio are automatically displayed on the mobile app with white padding on the top/bottom or sides of the image, to fit the ratio without being cropped. Although a 3:2 aspect ratio, or 1200 x 800, displays fully without padding, LinkedIn recommend using the industry-standard 1200 x 627 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using the UGC posts, which according to the docs will eventually substitute the Shares API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share

I haven't had any luck due to the following [Bad request: Attempting to associate a ugc with an asset that's not owned by the author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201879/bad-request-attempting-to-associate-a-ugc-with-an-asset-thats-not-owned-by-the), but you may want to give it a shot.

Since you have access to richMedia API, maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For businees purposes, I am allowed to use only API's which are under Marketing Developer Platform - API's. Where as the API, you suggested is in Consumer Solutions Platform -API which is not for business. And in Marketing Developer Platform - API, there is a UGC Post but it is only for video shares.