# Create an image share using linked api v2 in php

Tags: php, mysql, http, curl

I'm not able to Create an Image Share

I've already tried "Create a Text Share", "Create an Article or URL Share" on this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin (it works)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$uploadurl = $content['value']['uploadMechanism']['com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest']['uploadUrl'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadurl);
$postData = array('upload-file' => $image_path,);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am getting an error when using the code

```
HTTP/2 400 
server: Play
set-cookie: lang=v=2&lang=en-us; Path=/; Domain=api.linkedin.com
date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 13:20:18 GMT
content-length: 0
x-li-fabric: prod-lsg1
x-li-pop: prod-tmu1-tls13
x-li-proto: http/2
x-li-uuid: yHH9/J1zqxUg49zQTisAAA==
set-cookie: lidc="b=SB01:g=126:u=36:i=1561468818:t=1561546488:s=AQFBkUrPOpXyD1XtJHm-uvTC74dEZLtT"
x-li-route-key: "b=SB01:g=126:u=36:i=1561468818:t=1561546488:s=AQFBkUrPOpXyD1XtJHm-uvTC74dEZLtT"
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the error you're receiving when you try this.  [ask]

Comment: we can't guess what your error is, please tell us

Comment: Is the problem that you're getting a "400" response from the server? If so it means that somehow you didn't supply the correct data to the server. Usually the response body would contain more details of what it expects you to send.

Comment: P.S. I remove the "api" tag - it has a big "DO NOT USE" label on it when you hover over it to get the description - always check the tags before you add them to your question - thanks.

Comment: Use this answer to share the image on linkedin with the v2 api
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777057/1564956

Comment: @kenlukas i got response when i tried to upload image to ulpoad url (which is came from assets?action=registerUpload request) , one main thing is when i run that code i am getting urn:li:share:id even there is an error in code.