# LinkedIn v2 API: How can upload an image using ugcPosts API?

Tags: rest, curl, postman, linkedin-api

I am working on posting image to linkedin using V2. I register an image using this end point https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload 
 as a result i get uploadUrl (end point to upload an image). 
The issue here that i don't know how to upload the image. In Linkedin Api doc they put curl command and i am not very familiar with that.
I try with postman import --> Paste Raw text[upload image api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uDwj.png)

But that don't show me really how to pass the image to upload.
Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my answer on a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902863/7844946

I think for Postman you can simply select the file by going to Body -> Binary -> Choose File.

Comment: thank you, did you get that problem  {"serviceErrorCode"=>100, "message"=>"Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/registerUploadRequest/recipes/relationshipType]", "status"=>403} when trying to register an image. I see that you're using ruby as me.

Comment: I remember seeing this error once, but I don't remember whether I got that for registering a video or an image, nor how I solved it. I kept getting another exception that was eventually fixed by the LinkedIn team: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201879/bad-request-attempting-to-associate-a-ugc-with-an-asset-thats-not-owned-by-the